# Hibernate queries MS SQL server table as datetime2 data type for datetime columns

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have a table in Microsoft SQL Server 2012 database as follows.

[image]

I have sample Spring boot application just to test retrieval of the data.

In entity class, joining_date is represented as below.

```
@Column(name = "joining_date")
private Date joiningDate;
```

And JpaRepository as below.

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepo extends CrudRepository<Employee, Integer> {
    Employee findByIdAndJoiningDate(Integer id, Date joiningDate);
}
```

I have test retrieval code as below in my service class.

```
Integer id = 1;
Employee employee = employeeRepo.findOne(id);
Employee employee1 = employeeRepo.findByIdAndJoiningDate(employee.getId(), employee.getJoiningDate());
```

When I execute the above test code, I see **datetime2** data type in SQL profiler where as my column data type is **datetime**. Here is the output from SQL profiler.

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=4
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P0 int,@P1 datetime2',N'select employee0_.id as id1_0_, employee0_.joining_date as joining_2_0_ from tb_employee employee0_ where employee0_.id=@P0 and employee0_.joining_date=@P1                ',1,'2019-11-25 18:53:48.4870000'
select @p1
```

**How can I force MS SQL to be executed as datetime instead of datetime2?**

Please note I have also tried writing custom dialect. But that did not help

```
public class ModifiedSQLServerDialect extends SQLServer2012Dialect {
    public ModifiedSQLServerDialect () {
        super();
        this.registerColumnType( Types.TIMESTAMP, "datetime" );
    }
}
```

and in application.properties,

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect: com.example.demo.config.ModifiedSQLServerDialect
```

Help is much appreciated.